# SKAction not working as expected

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

Hi I have a sequence of action that run forever to generate obstacles in a side scrolling game. But instead of generating random pictures and heights from my textures it keeps the same ones it generated the first time it ran the SKActions...

Can someone solve this? I am trying not to use

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("setUpMountains"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

As it lowers my FPS for some reason

```
    func setUpMountains() {

    let gapHeight = user.size.height * 3
    var movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 3.0)

    var randomNumber = arc4random() % 3
    if randomNumber == 0 {
        mountainTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"RedMountain.png")
    } else if randomNumber == 1 {
        mountainTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"OrangeMountain.png")
    } else {
        mountainTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"BeigeMountain.png")
    }
    var randomMountain = SKSpriteNode(texture: mountainTexture)
    randomMountain.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.width, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - gapHeight - CGFloat(movementAmount))
    randomMountain.zPosition = 8
    randomMountain.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: mountainTexture, size: mountainTexture.size())
    randomMountain.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
//        randomMountain.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectCategory
    movingObjects.addChild(randomMountain)

    //spawning mountains
    var distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + mountainTexture.size().width
    var moveMountain = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval (distanceToMove * 0.01))
    var replaceMountain = SKAction.moveByX(distanceToMove, y: 0, duration: 0)
    //var removeMountain = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    var moveAndRemoveMountain = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveMountain, replaceMountain]))

    randomMountain.runAction(moveAndRemoveMountain)

}
```

Comment: why are you using an NSTimer? It doesn't work well with sprite kit. Use SKAction with a waitForDuration instead?

Comment: and can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do in the code?

Comment: hey @rakeshbs I am trying to call this function every x seconds to generate new random sized obstacles. If i use the repeatActionForever then it will just use the same randomMountain generated the first time instead of regenerating new ones. Can you show me how .waitForDuration would change that?

Comment: I was using NSTimer to call selector with delay...but it ruins my FPS

Comment: ok. don't you want to remove the existing mountains before adding the new mountains?

Comment: yes that too. i had a removeFromParent but it did nothing with my current set up

Comment: Will the mountains have the width of the screen?

Comment: @rakeshbs no im just changing the height, the width varies by how much they stick out since they are triangular shaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the textures each time, cache the textures once in an array, for e.g. `mountains` in the following code.

Use an `SKAction sequence` with a wait duration instead of an NSTimer to repeatedly execute functions.

You don't need the `repeatActionForever` action in the setup mountains since the generated obstacles are removed once they go out of the screen using `removeParent`.

```
var mountains : [SKTexture] = []

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    mountains = [SKTexture(imageNamed:"RedMountain.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"OrangeMountain.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"BeigeMountain.png")]

    let generateMountains = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        self.setUpMountains()
    }
    let generateObstaclesPeriodically = SKAction.repeatActionForever (SKAction.sequence([generateMountains,SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0)]))
     self.runAction(generateObstaclesPeriodically)
}


func setUpMountains() {

    let gapHeight = user.size.height * 3
    var movementAmount = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 3.0)

    var randomNumber = arc4random() % 3
    let mountainTexture = mountains[randomNumber]

    var randomMountain = SKSpriteNode(texture: mountainTexture)
    randomMountain.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.width, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - gapHeight - CGFloat(movementAmount))
    randomMountain.zPosition = 8
    randomMountain.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: mountainTexture, size: mountainTexture.size())
    randomMountain.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    movingObjects.addChild(randomMountain)

    //spawning mountains
    var distanceToMove = self.frame.size.width + mountainTexture.size().width
    var moveMountain = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval (distanceToMove * 0.01))
    var removeMountain = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    var moveAndRemoveMountain = SKAction.sequence([moveMountain, removeMountain])

    randomMountain.runAction(moveAndRemoveMountain)

}
```

To remove an SKAction you can give a key to the `SKAction` while adding it and use the key to remove it from the node.

```
 self.runAction(generateObstaclesPeriodically, withKey: "generateObstaclesPeriodically")
 self.removeActionForKey("generateObstaclesPeriodically")
```

Comment: one more thing if you can please help me... when the user loses, or app enters background...etc these functions are still creating nodes which will eventually lead to a crash. Is there a way to stop them without reseting the game?

Comment: The `SKAction` is paused automatically when app enters background and resumes when it comes back to foreground.  Check my updated answer for removing an action

Answer (score 0):

@rakeshbs thanks a lot that seems to work but i changed it to this instead

```
mountains = [SKTexture(imageNamed:"RedMountain.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"OrangeMountain.png"),SKTexture(imageNamed:"BeigeMountain.png")]

    let generateMountains = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        self.setUpMountains()
    }
    let generateObstaclesPeriodically = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([generateMountains,SKAction.waitForDuration(4.0)]))
    self.runAction(generateObstaclesPeriodically)
```